# how to force сadvisor not to give empty labels in prometheus in cluster kubernetes?

Tags: kubernetes, monitoring, cadvisor

we have a problem, we have cadvisor installed as a daemonset with hostport setup. We request metrics at , for example, worker5:31194/metrics and the request takes a very long time, about 40 seconds. As I understand it, the problem is related to the fact that cadvisor gives away extra empty labels.

looks like

```
container_cpu_cfs_periods_total{container_label_annotation_cni_projectcalico_org_containerID="",container_label_annotation_cni_projectcalico_org_podIP="",container_label_annotation_cni_projectcalico_org_podIPs="",container_label_annotation_io_kubernetes_container_hash="",container_label_annotation_io_kubernetes_container_ports="",container_label_annotation_io_kubernetes_container_preStopHandler="",container_label_annotation_io_kubernetes_container_restartCount="",container_label_annotation_io_kubernetes_container_terminationMessagePath="",container_label_annotation_io_kubernetes_container_terminationMessagePolicy="",container_label_annotation_io_kubernetes_pod_terminationGracePeriod="",container_label_annotation_kubernetes_io_config_seen="",container_label_annotation_kubernetes_io_config_source="",container_label_app="",container_label_app_kubernetes_io_component="",container_label_app_kubernetes_io_instance="",container_label_app_kubernetes_io_name="",container_label_app_kubernetes_io_version="",container_label_architecture="",container_label_build_date="",container_label_build_id="",container_label_com_redhat_build_host="",container_label_com_redhat_component="",container_label_com_redhat_license_terms="",container_label_control_plane="",container_label_controller_revision_hash="",container_label_description="",container_label_distribution_scope="",container_label_git_commit="",container_label_io_k8s_description="",container_label_io_k8s_display_name="",container_label_io_kubernetes_container_logpath="",container_label_io_kubernetes_container_name="",container_label_io_kubernetes_docker_type="",container_label_io_kubernetes_pod_name="",container_label_io_kubernetes_pod_namespace="",container_label_io_kubernetes_pod_uid="",container_label_io_kubernetes_sandbox_id="",container_label_io_openshift_expose_services="",container_label_io_openshift_tags="",container_label_io_rancher_rke_container_name="",container_label_k8s_app="",container_label_license="",container_label_maintainer="",container_label_name="",container_label_org_label_schema_build_date="",container_label_org_label_schema_license="",container_label_org_label_schema_name="",container_label_org_label_schema_schema_version="",container_label_org_label_schema_url="",container_label_org_label_schema_vcs_ref="",container_label_org_label_schema_vcs_url="",container_label_org_label_schema_vendor="",container_label_org_label_schema_version="",container_label_org_opencontainers_image_created="",container_label_org_opencontainers_image_description="",container_label_org_opencontainers_image_documentation="",container_label_org_opencontainers_image_licenses="",container_label_org_opencontainers_image_revision="",container_label_org_opencontainers_image_source="",container_label_org_opencontainers_image_title="",container_label_org_opencontainers_image_url="",container_label_org_opencontainers_image_vendor="",container_label_org_opencontainers_image_version="",container_label_pod_template_generation="",container_label_pod_template_hash="",container_label_release="",container_label_summary="",container_label_url="",container_label_vcs_ref="",container_label_vcs_type="",container_label_vendor="",container_label_version="",id="/kubepods/burstable/pod080e6da8-7f00-403d-a8de-3f93db373776",image="",name=""} 3.572708e+06
```

is there any solution to remove the empty label or remove the label altogether?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found two parameters, the first one suited me, but you never know who will need the second, there is little information, so I decided to post the answer

> -store_container_labels
>
> ```
>           convert  container  labels  and  environment  variables  into  labels on prometheus
>           metrics for each container. If flag set to false, then only  metrics  exported  are
>           container name, first alias, and image name (default true)
> ```
>
> -whitelisted_container_labels string
>
> ```
>           comma  separated  list  of container labels to be converted to labels on prometheus
>           metrics for each container. store_container_labels must be set to false for this to
>           take effect.
> ```